# Transfer Files from Windows 10 Desktop to Unix Server Ubuntu

Tags: unix, ftp, sftp, ubuntu-14.04

How can I Transfer Files from Windows 10 Desktop to Unix Server Ubuntu - without using a browser, or FTP ?

Is there any other way, FTP or SFTP or thinlinc dont work.

I tried WinSCP, and Mobaxterm to connect to the servers but neither would connect properly.   WinSCP authenticates my username and password then just times out and says the host is not communicating for 15 seconds then says it cannot initialize SFTP protocol. When I try MobaXterm using SFTP, it says SSHPUBLICKEY authentication failed, SSHPUBLICKEYAGENT authentication failed, but SSH authentication password (my account) passed, but I cant download or upload anything, most likely due to KEY authentication failing (not sure what that is).

This is a university server.  The servers are all connected over the internet,  I want to transfer files over their network from my desktop Windows computer to their UNIX server computers.  Typically, we use thinlinc to connect to a server and use thinlinc to do remote UNIX work on Ubuntu.

I cannot add anything on to their unix servers or modify it - I just connect from home.

Next I tried other clients like thinlinc and thinlinc tries to connect and just freezes up and doesnt respond.  I am wondering if the SSH is just timed out.  I tried to install thinlinc on other computers and same thing, using my user name and password, it just freezes and doesnt connect for hours.

Comment: Samba or USB flash drive, AKA sneakernet

Comment: I myself use the built in "stuff" in [mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).  Use it to SSH into your Linux bux and simply drag and drop.  It is *like* ftp.. but I don't think that it is (no ftp server or setup).. try it yourself.  If this works for you, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Thats not working right now.  I tried FTP and SFTP how to do I SSH for files

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain exactly how you tried to use SFTP and FTP and how they failed. Did you get any error messages? What did they say? Are these computers connected to a network? The same network? Are they connected to the Internet? Or do you want to transfer the files without using networking?

Comment: I edited my comment to include your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment yet to further clarify on your problem)

For copying files to Unix or GNU/Linux Systems you usually use SSH/SFTP or SCP.

You can setup a Samba Server on the Unix box. Windows should support that natively without using any 3rd Party application.

However, SFTP is usually very more simple to setup - often it is enabled by default. Of course it requires root privileges to enable.

If it is not enabled by default and you are using openssh server which most distributions come with (and Ubuntu should too), check:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and make sure the line

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

is not commented out.

If you changed the file, restart the sshd

```
(sudo) service ssh restart
```

SFTP Clients to recommend when using Windows:

- WinSCP
- Filezilla

Just to name 2 Tools I have used myself which are very lean and also free to use.

hth